# Error while taking an image capture while pressing button

Tags: pi-3, python

I have set up a on my bread board a button and trying to take images when I press it. I also have a led that turns on while pressing the button. 
All works fine, however, when I run the python script, it does not wait for me to press the button and automatically takes the image with an error

Here are images of my board and Pi.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Below is my code and the error

```
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

sleepTime = 0.1

#GPIO pin components
lightPin = 4
buttonPin = 17

GPIO.setup(lightPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.output(lightPin, False)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(lightPin, not GPIO.input(buttonPin))
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.capture('image.jpg')
        sleep(sleepTime)

finally:
    GPIO.output(lightPin, False)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The error

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================= RESTART: /home/pi/Desktop/doorbelPhoto.py =================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/doorbelPhoto.py", line 25, in <module>
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the camera object being re-initialised (camera = picamera.PiCamera()) - move this outside the while loop. There is also nothing waiting for a button press.

```
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

sleepTime = 0.1

#GPIO pin components
lightPin = 4
buttonPin = 17
camera = picamera.PiCamera()

GPIO.setup(lightPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.output(lightPin, False)

try:
    while True:
        while True:
            press = GPIO.input(buttonPin)
            if (press == 1):
                break
            GPIO.output(lightPin, not GPIO.input(buttonPin))
            print('capture')
            camera.capture('image.jpg')
            sleep(sleepTime)
        GPIO.output(lightPin, 0)
        sleep(sleepTime)
finally:
    GPIO.output(lightPin, False)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: does not work. keeps on printing capture non stop and does nothing on press of button.

Comment: Works for me. Can you post a photo of your breadboard setup and connection to the GPIO?

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: It works. I had 2 lines of code indented in a wrong way. my bad. Thanks a lot for your time.